# French to English translation with NLTK 3

Tags: python, nltk

I am using NLTK 3 and I have translated English words to French:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as omw
>>> ss =  omw.synsets('dog')[0]
>>> ss.lemmas(lang='fre')
[Lemma('dog.n.01.chien'), Lemma('dog.n.01.canis_familiaris')]
```

But I couldn't do the opposite, i.e. translate a French word to English. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

When I try Babelfish, I keep getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'translate'.

According to the issue discussed [here](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/265)

> There is no longer http://babelfish.yahoo.com/translate_txt - it redirects to http://www.microsofttranslator.com/ which is an another translator service with different API.

and, if you look into the official documentation [here](http://pythonhosted.org//babelfish/api/language.html), there is no talk about translation.

Comment: As @alvas pointed out `babelfish` is no longer supported in NLTK3. So you have to find other solution.